# Is there a simple way to fill a designed website using Razor Pages and .NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, razor-pages, .net-5

I'm trying to make a News web app with .NET 5 and Razor Pages and want to display all the articles brought from [NewsAPI](https://newsapi.org/). I'm using C#, also, I'm using bootstrap for styling. Something like this:

```
    <div class="container">
    @{
        var Articles = IndexModel.Articles; // I get this articles from logic within IndexMode.cshtml.cs
        foreach (var article in IndexModel.Articles)
        {
            <div class="card bg-dark text-white" style="background-color: black;">
                <a href="@article.Url">
                    <img class="card-img fluid" src="@article.UrlToImage" alt="Card img" style="opacity: 0.5;">
                </a>
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h5 class="card-title">@article.Title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">@article.Description</p>
                    <p class="card-text">@article.PublishedAt</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```

Pretty simple. But i want the site to have multiple rows and structure, not only a list of the same bootstrap card.

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo2vW.jpg)

The other way to do this is just to replace all the references of those articles one by one, something like this:

```
<div class="container-scroller">
  <div class="main-panel">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="banner-top-thumb-wrap">
        <div class="d-lg-flex justify-content-between align-items-center ">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between  mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-truncate">
            <div><a href="@SEARCH_A[1].Url">
              <img
                src="@SEARCH_A[1].UrlToImage"
                alt="ArticlesRequestedElonMusk[1].image"
                class="banner-top-thumb "
                
              /></a>
            </div>
            <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold  ">
              @SEARCH_A[1].Title
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-truncate">
            <div><a href="@SEARCH_A[2].Url">
              <img
                src="@SEARCH_A[2].UrlToImage"
                alt="ArticlesRequestedElonMusk[2].UrlToImage"
                class="banner-top-thumb"
                
              /></a>
            </div>
            <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-truncate ">
              @SEARCH_A[2].Title
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-truncate">
            <div><a href="@SEARCH_A[3].Url">
              <img
                src="@SEARCH_A[3].UrlToImage"
                alt="ArticlesRequestedElonMusk[3].Title"
                class="banner-top-thumb"
              /></a>
            </div>
            <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-truncate ">
              @SEARCH_A[3].Title
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3 mb-lg-0 text-truncate">
            <div><a href="@SEARCH_A[4].Url">
              <img
                src="@SEARCH_A[4].UrlToImage"
                alt="ArticlesRequestedElonMusk[4].Title"
                class="banner-top-thumb"
              /></a>
            </div>
            <h5 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-truncate">
              @SEARCH_A[4].Title
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="main-banner-carousel">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-content-wrapper mb-2">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold">
                    @SEARCH_A[0].Title  @* Title *@
                  </h1>
                  <h5 class="font-weight-normal  m-0">
                    @SEARCH_A[0].Description
                  </h5>
                  <p class="text-color m-0 pt-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">@SEARCH_A[0].PublishedAt</span> @* Published at *@
                    <i class="mdi mdi-bookmark-outline mr-3"></i>
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">126</span>
                    <i class="mdi mdi-comment-outline"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-image" style="max-height: 100%;">
                  <img class="image-fluid" src="@SEARCH_A[0].UrlToImage" alt="an image should be here" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-content-wrapper mb-2">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold">
                    @SEARCH_A[5].Title
                  </h1>
                  <h5 class="font-weight-normal  m-0">
                    @SEARCH_A[5].Description
                  </h5>
                  <p class="text-color m-0 pt-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">@SEARCH_A[5].PublishedAt</span>
                    <i class="mdi mdi-bookmark-outline mr-3"></i>
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">@SEARCH_A[5].Source</span>
                    <i class="mdi mdi-comment-outline"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-image img-fluid">
                  <img src="@SEARCH_A[5].UrlToImage" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <div class="carousel-content-wrapper mb-2">
                <div class="carousel-content">
                  <h1 class="font-weight-bold">
                    @SEARCH_A[6].Title
                  </h1>
                  <h5 class="font-weight-normal  m-0">
                    @SEARCH_A[6].Description
                  </h5>
                  <p class="text-color m-0 pt-2 d-flex align-items-center">
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">@SEARCH_A[6].PublishedAt</span>
                    <i class="mdi mdi-bookmark-outline mr-3"></i>
                    <span class="fs-10 mr-1">@SEARCH_A[6].Source</span>
                    <i class="mdi mdi-comment-outline"></i>
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-image img-fluid">
                  <img src="@SEARCH_A[6].UrlToImage" alt="" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

This way of doing it respects the original design and layout of website, but:

- I have to ensure there's enough articles to fill the existing layout or a null reference exception may occur
- If I where to change any reference of determined article it will most likely broke the other ones.

Here's my solution for two columns from the same loop:

```
var NounList = articles.Where(a => a.Id % 2 != 0).ToList();
var PairList = articles.Where(a => a.Id % 2 == 0).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i <= (articles.Count / 2) - 1; i++)
            {
                <div class="card-group">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="@NounList[i].Url">
                        <img src="@NounList[i].UrlToImage" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">@NounList[i].Title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">@NounList[i].Description</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">@NounList[i].PublishedAt</small></p>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="@PairList[i].Url">
                        <img src="@PairList[i].UrlToImage" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">@PairList[i].Title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">@PairList[i].Description</p>
                            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">@PairList[i].PublishedAt</small></p>
                        </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

Is there a simplest way to fill with data a designed website using Razor Pages and .NET?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is "simple" to you? What did you try and why was it too complicated?

Comment: Depends on the design and the website, I should think. I mean, if a design calls for hundreds of user-configurable widgets placed wherever the user wants on the page (within preset limits, natch), that would be more difficult that a site with a single nav menu, a header, footer, and content area.

Comment: @Xerillio thanks. Well, i guess i'm looking for other ways of doing it. I'm filling a bootstrap template with this data but the process of replacement of all the references to Article[0].description ... Article[0].Title .... etc is very tedious

Comment: @HereticMonkey right, I guess it depends on how you get the data.

Answer (score 0):

To create the layout you want using Bootstrap, you need to create a container (). Next, create a row (). Then, add the desired number of columns (tags with appropriate .col-*-* classes). Note that numbers in .col-*-* should always add up to 12 for each row.

For example, if you want to display four columns in a row, use the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 50px 0;
    }

    .box {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #aaa;
        margin: 20px 0;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 200px;
        border: 2px #ccc solid;
        color: darkblue;
    }
</style>

<!-- 4 columns -->
<h3>4 Columns</h3>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="card">
                    <span> ... card content</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="card">
                    <span> ... card content</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="card">
                    <span> ... card content</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="card">
                    <span> ... card content</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

the result as below:

[image]

More detail information, refer the following links:

[Bootstrap Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

[Bootstrap 4 Columns with Multiple Breakpoints](https://codepen.io/cristinaconacel/pen/mjZBPO)

[Bootstrap Responsive Card thumbnail](https://codepen.io/wisnust10/pen/BKjNNR)

Comment: I would recommend updating your examples and linked resources to use a newer version of Bootstrap instead of the ~6 year old Bootstrap 3.x

Comment: Hi @Xerillio, Thanks for recommending me about that. I have updated the sample. Have a nice day!